# Javascript get day of week from date

Tags: javascript, date

I am creating a reservation application in one of my classes. In the app, a user is trying to create a recurring reservation by giving a start date and end date and a day of the week they want the reservation. I want to return a list of dates that they have reservations on; here's an example

Start Date: 02/01/2015
End Date: 03/01/2015
Days of the Week: Monday and Wednesday.

In this example, I want to return all the Mondays and Wednesdays during this time. I would like to do this in Javascript.

Comment: I don't see it tagged, but are you using moment.js?

Comment: `I would like to do this in Javascript.` What is the stopper?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the dates using:

```
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
```

And check if the day of the week is monday or wednesday using:

```
tomorrow.getDay()
```

Comment: Hmm, that's good. I'm not sure why I thought this was much more complicated than it is. I'm going to try this out!

Comment: That should work, today would be your first date and you would put those two lines inside of a while loop recording the dates that are equal to mon and wed in an array. If the today date equals your final date break the loop.